# I accidentally popped a tick that was on my dog's eyelids

Tags: dogs, safety, diseases, ticks

I accidentally popped a tick on my dog's eyelids and unfortunately blood got on his eyes; the blood went away in a while, but was the blood that got to his eyes will be dangerous? What can I do myself? Thank you!

Comment: Tick are never orphans ; I would look all over your dog including deep in its ears. I would not worry much about it you got the head. On a return trip from Mo in springtime , The kids picked about 30 ticks off an Irish Setter after a 3 day visit . I am sure they did not get all heads but there was no subsequent problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you need to worry, the blood is from your dog and it is mixed with an anticoagulant the ticks produce to keep the blood flowing, so the tick can feed on the blood.

The danger with ticks is they can transfer illness to your dog, so the best you can do now is to keep an eye on your dog to see if there is swelling around the bite area, and to keep an eye on your dog to see if your dog gets ill and/or gets a fever.

If your dog shows sign of illness, you need to contact your vet for treatment. You might want to call your vet to get advice about this, as there are some areas where ticks cause a larger danger to your dog.

It is not likely your dog gets infected via the eyes, as the liquid in the eyes of mammals does protect against infections to a large degree.

Comment: @Dennis If the tick popped, the head is probably still burried inside the skin. If you can see it or grab it with some tweezers, you should try removing it. If not (or if you're not confident you can do it without further hurting your dog), you should probably ask a vet for help. If the head remains inside the skin, it can cause inflammation.

Comment: @Elmy you are right but i my experience getting the remaining body parts of the tick out is wery hard,asking the vet for help is good advice.

Answer (score 2):

Popping the tick does not more damage then the bite itself has done. But different as the other answers say, **you should be worried about tick bites** in general.

### **Lyme Borreliosis Disease**

It is caused by a bacterium transmitted by minimum 4 different kinds of ticks. In some US states around 50% of ticks can be infected with them. They infect humans, dogs, horses and maybe cats. I am from Europe, and here also Borreliosis is an issue, the dog of my parents-in-law died of it.

> The signs of Lyme disease vary. Many animals can have Lyme disease and show no signs. In dogs, the most common signs include fever, loss of appetite, painful or swollen joints, lameness that comes and goes, swollen lymph nodes, and lethargy. If Lyme disease is left untreated it can lead to damage in the kidneys, nervous system, and heart. **Lyme disease affecting the kidneys is the second most common syndrome in dogs and is generally fatal.**

(source: [Lyme Disease (Lyme Borreliosis) in Dogs](https://www.msdvetmanual.com/dog-owners/disorders-affecting-multiple-body-systems-of-dogs/lyme-disease-lyme-borreliosis-in-dogs) by the MSD MANUAL Veterinary Manual, a US organization)

> Lyme disease is the most common disease spread by ticks in the Northern Hemisphere.[15] It is estimated to affect 300,000 people a year in the United States and 65,000 people a year in Europe.[2][4]

(source: [Wikipedia Lyme disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyme_disease))

### Please do not underestimate this disease!

**Before the walk:**

To avoid being infected, humans and animals should be treated regularly with a readily available, effective, tick-control product. Also, humans can wear clothes, which cover especially the ankles (trousers into the socks/shoes) and with long arms (imagine children who touch every bush, or bend down to inspect all discoveries).

**During the walk:**

Ticks live in high grass and bushes at heights of around the hip height of humans. They climb it and wait for warm blooded animals to graze through it. Then they let go and take hold onto this animals. They will wander the body until they find an area with thin skin to do their bite. This is especially in the **human** armpit, hollow of the knee, genital area and behind the ears and in the neck. Some people can feel them wander, because they feel an itching. Then one should be attentive and have a look, what causes the itch, rather than to scratch it blindly.

**After the walk:**

Also, one can avoid being bitten by changing clothes when coming home and having a close look for wandering ticks in front of a mirror. Children may need assistance. In humans they avoid hairy areas (remember to control armpit, hollow of the knee, genital area, behind the ears and in the neck). In **dogs** they also search for less hairy areas, for example the genital area, belly, inside the ears and similar. In long haired dogs combing after a walk in wild areas can help to retrieve ticks (which are still wandering) from the fur.

**About the wandering:**

> Sie hängen sich anschließend an alles, was ihren jeweiligen Aufenthaltsort streift und krabbeln dann oft bei Tier und Menschen bis zu mehreren Stunden lang am Körper umher, bis sie eine passende Einstichstelle gefunden haben. Zecken sind dabei sehr wählerisch und bevorzugen etwas feuchte, warme und gut durchblutete, dünne Haut. Beim Menschen sind besonders die Kniekehlen, der Haaransatz, die Leistenbeuge und die feine Haut hinter den Ohren ein beliebtes Ziel.

(source: [German Wikipedia about ticks](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zecken))

Translation:

> They will hang on all beings, which roams their actual place and then wander often at humans and animals **multiple hours** over the body, until they find a suiting bite-spot. Ticks are picky in this and favor kind of humid, warm and thin skin areas, well supplied with blood. At humans especially the hollow of the knee, the hairline, the groin and the fine skin behind the ears are popular aims.

Because they probably wander multiple hours, there is a good chance to get rid of them after the walk, before they do their biting.

Some people mark the bitten area with some ink marker to control later if there will appear the first symptom: **"an expanding red rash, known as erythema migrans, that appears at the site of the tick bite about a week after it occurred."** (linked Wikipedia article)

Other recommended actions for dogs:

> Prevention of Lyme Disease
>
> - Dogs should be treated regularly with a readily available, effective, tick-control product. Ask your veterinarian to recommend the best product for your pet.
> - In areas where Lyme disease is common, ask your veterinarian about whether vaccination is recommended.
> - Dogs should be routinely checked for ticks after they have been outside, especially if they have been in tall grass and brush during the spring, summer, or fall.
> - Remove any ticks by using fine-pointed tweezers to grasp the head of the tick (right where it enters the skin). Pull the tick straight off, making sure not to grasp or squeeze its body.
> - Dogs should be brushed regularly. Watch carefully for any ticks that are removed and capture and dispose of them before they can either reattach to the dog or migrate to other pets or people in the household.

(source: [Lyme Disease (Lyme Borreliosis) in Dogs](https://www.msdvetmanual.com/dog-owners/disorders-affecting-multiple-body-systems-of-dogs/lyme-disease-lyme-borreliosis-in-dogs) by the MSD MANUAL Veterinary Manual, a US organization)

Also, have a look into this answer [How long does it take a tick to infect my pet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18647/how-long-does-it-take-a-tick-to-infect-my-pet/18690#18690)